# I'm using C#, Windows Store App template is missing, how can I fix this?

Tags: c#, templates, project

I'm studying C# with the book, 'Head First C#' and the book requires me to make a new project using the Windows Store App Template. However, I cannot find the option when trying to make one. Could you help me out here? I want to know what is the problem and how to fix it.

I'm using Windows 8.1 Embedded Edition and Visual Studio Community. If there is anything you need to know more to fix this issue, please comment me.

Answer (score 0):

When you click File > New > Project, Open up the 'Templates' menu on the left of the newly popped up dialog box, then find Visual C# > Windows > Windows 8 > Universal > Blank App (Universal Windows 8.1)

You might need to download the templates within Visual Studio first. A link should be in the same dialog, for 'Windows Metro Apps' or something similar

Comment: I'll try it out as soon as I can get to my laptop, thank you:)

Comment: I'm trying this out, and do you mean that this template is the same as Store App template?